# figures on the left with corresponding texts on the right

Tags: wrapfigure, overleaf, text

I have some figures and would like to add them on the left with a corresponding text on the right, with letters indicating the order, like the following image.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! What have you tried so far? Please add a minimal working example (MWE) showing your current setup.

Comment: You can achive this kind of layout in a lot of different ways. Please clarify: Should the letters on the left be auto-generated? Do the images and texts all fit onto a single page or do you need pagebreaks between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it using a `tabular`.

```
% figtextprob.tex  SE 554582
%\documentclass{memoir} % or the article/report/book class with tabularx
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for including graphical images
\usepackage{mwe}      % provides some sample images

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{0.5cm}m{0.2\textwidth}m{0.7\textwidth}}
(H) & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a} & His colleague
  asks him, ``Why are you so cold?'' \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{m{0.5cm}m{0.2\textwidth}m{0.7\textwidth}}
(I) & \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b} & Bill replies,
  ``I forgot my coat, and it started snowing while I was walking to work!'' \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you use the `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report` and `article` classes) you don't need the `tabularx` package.

If everything will fit on one page then put all the entries into a single `tabular` otherwise one entry per `tabular` so that page breaks can be done automatically.

Adjust the lengths as appropriate for your document.

If you want more information on the `tabular` settings read *Chapter 11 Rows and columns* in the `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memnoir`).

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: Why do you load the `tabularx` package in this specific MWE? You don't seem to need it since there is no `tabularx` environment in your code.

Comment: @leandris If I don't load `tabularx` then I get an error message "Illegal character in array arg." followed by `l.9 ...}{m{0.5cm}m{ ` which continues on but I can't be bothered to type it all in.